Empty Pages in Latex, no Pagebreak
Why is a blank page sometimes inserted after tables, even though I do not enter a pagebreak command? How can I prevent this? The tables seem to fit on the page.
EDIT:
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{anyfontsize}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{geometry}
\usepackage[pdftex]{graphicx, color}
\usepackage[graphicx]{realboxes}
\usepackage{rotating}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\usepackage[table]{xcolor}
\usepackage{wrapfig}
\usepackage{forest}
\useforestlibrary{edges}

\newcolumntype{P}[1]{>{\centering\arraybackslash}p{#1}} 
\setlength{\tabcolsep}{11pt}
\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{2.5}

\begin{document}
\begin{wraptable}{l}{5.5cm}
    \caption{Scaling Ansatz}
    \label{sa}
    {\rowcolors{2}{gray!10!white!100}{gray!25!white!100}
    \fontsize{9pt}{9pt}\selectfont
    \Rotatebox{90}{
    \begin{tabular}{
    |P{2.4cm}|P{2.3cm}|P{1.3cm}|P{1.3cm}|P{2cm}|P{1.15cm}|P{1.8cm}|P{0.25cm}|}
        \hline
        \multicolumn{8}{c}{} \\
        \hline
        & \textbf{Horiz. scale} & \textbf{x} & \textbf{y} & \textbf{Temp. scale} & \textbf{t} & \textbf{Vert. scale} & \textbf{z} \\
        \hline
        Non-dimens. & $h_{\text{sc}}\sim\qty{11}{km}$ & $x$ & $y$ & $t_{\text{ref}}\sim\qty{15}{min}$ & $t$ & $h_{\text{sc}}\sim\qty{11}{km}$ & $z$\\
        Mesoscale & $L_{\text{meso}}\sim\qty{150}{km}$ & $x_{\text{m}}=\epsilon\,x$ & $y_{\text{m}}=\epsilon\,y$ & $T_{\text{meso}}\sim\qty{3.5}{h}$ & $t_{\text{m}}=\epsilon\,t$ & $h_{\text{sc}}\sim\qty{11}{km}$ & $z$ \\
        Synoptic Scale & $L_{\text{syn}}\sim\qty{1100}{km}$ & $x_{\text{s}}=\epsilon^2\,x$ & $y_{\text{s}}=\epsilon^2\,y$ & $T_{\text{syn}}\sim\qty{1}{d}$ & $t_{\text{s}}=\epsilon^2\,t$ & $h_{\text{sc}}\sim\qty{11}{km}$ & $z$ \\
        \hline
    \end{tabular}}}
    \centering
\end{wraptable}
\section{A}
Text
\clearpage
\section{B}
\begin{sideways}
  \parbox{\textheight}{%
  \centering
  \begin{forest}
    forked edges,
    for tree={
      line width=1pt,
      edge+={line width=1pt},
      draw,
      align=left,
      tier/.option=level,
    },
    s sep'+=20pt,
    [\large{Synoptic-Scale Dynaics}, fill=white
      [Thermodynamic Eq.
      [(1)]
      ]
      [PV Eq.
      [(2)]
      ]
      [Continuity Eq.
            [(3)]
      [(4)]
      ]
      [Horiz. Momentum Eq.
      [(5)]
      ]
      [Hydrostatic Balance Eq.
      [(6)]
      ]
    ]
  \end{forest}
}
\end{sideways}
\end{document}


Please add a short, but compilable test file which allows us to reproduce the problem. It should include a class, the necessary packages and a document environment.

Are you by any chance using something like book and uses \chapter's? Chapter normally start on odd pages (right hand) and thus may insert blank pages if the last page of the preceeding page ended on a an odd page. If that is not the ase we need sample code as sam has already asked for.

@daleif  I added some code

why using wraptable here??

@DavidCarlisle because I'll add more text next to the table


You cannot have wraptable before a \section.

Your table is oversized.

The sideways “forest” is too big. Reducing 20pt to 15pt solves the issue.


Regarding point 3, it creates an empty page because TeX is trying to find a page break point, but since it is not allowed to break a page after a section title, it finds none, so it outputs a blank page; at the second attempt, it raises its hands and outputs an overfull page.
If you don't reduce the size of the tree, you won't be able to get anything sensible.
Other points to note.

anyfontsize is obsolete
the option pdftex should not be passed to graphicx
xcolor already loads color
setting \tabcolsep to 11pt is really too much
similarly for \arraystretch set to 2.5
instead of \fontsize{9}{9}\selectfont use just \small
\centering should be at the beginning, not at the end
the default style for captions in article is below tables; setting it above produces bad spacing
T_{\text{meso}} is wrong, use T_{\mathrm{meso}}
\textbf{x} should be, if any, \boldmath$x$
there's no need of \, between \epsilon and x

\documentclass{article}

%\usepackage{anyfontsize}% no!!!
%\usepackage{float}% dont' use [H]
\usepackage{geometry}
\usepackage{graphicx}% no pdftex option
\usepackage[graphicx]{realboxes}
\usepackage{rotating}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\usepackage[table]{xcolor}
\usepackage{wrapfig}
\usepackage{forest}
\useforestlibrary{edges}

\usepackage{lipsum}

\newcolumntype{P}[1]{>{\centering\arraybackslash}p{#1}} 
%\setlength{\tabcolsep}{11pt}% really?
%\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{2.5}% really?

\begin{document}

\section{A title}

\begin{wraptable}{l}{5.5cm}
\centering
\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{2}% local
    \rowcolors{2}{gray!10!white!100}{gray!25!white!100}
    \small
    \Rotatebox{90}{%
    \begin{tabular}{|*{8}{c|}}
        \hline
        & \textbf{Horiz. scale} & \boldmath$x$ & \boldmath$y$ & \textbf{Temp. scale} & \boldmath$t$ & \textbf{Vert. scale} & \boldmath$z$ \\
        \hline
        Non-dimens. & $h_{\mathrm{sc}}\sim\qty{11}{km}$ & $x$ & $y$ & $t_{\mathrm{ref}}\sim\qty{15}{min}$ & $t$ & $h_{\mathrm{sc}}\sim\qty{11}{km}$ & $z$\\
        Mesoscale & $L_{\mathrm{meso}}\sim\qty{150}{km}$ & $x_{\mathrm{m}}=\epsilon x$ & $y_{\mathrm{m}}=\epsilon y$ & $T_{\mathrm{meso}}\sim\qty{3.5}{h}$ & $t_{\mathrm{m}}=\epsilon t$ & $h_{\mathrm{sc}}\sim\qty{11}{km}$ & $z$ \\
        Synoptic Scale & $L_{\mathrm{syn}}\sim\qty{1100}{km}$ & $x_{\mathrm{s}}=\epsilon^2 x$ & $y_{\mathrm{s}}=\epsilon^2 y$ & $T_{\mathrm{syn}}\sim\qty{1}{d}$ & $t_{\mathrm{s}}=\epsilon^2 t$ & $h_{\mathrm{sc}}\sim\qty{11}{km}$ & $z$ \\
        \hline
    \end{tabular}}
    \caption{Scaling Ansatz}
    \label{sa}
\end{wraptable}

\lipsum[1-2]

\clearpage

\section{B}

\begin{sideways}
  \begin{forest}
    forked edges,
    for tree={
      line width=1pt,
      edge+={line width=1pt},
      draw,
      align=left,
      tier/.option=level,
    },
    s sep'+=15pt,
    [\large{Synoptic-Scale Dynaics}, fill=white
      [Thermodynamic Eq.
      [(1)]
      ]
      [PV Eq.
      [(2)]
      ]
      [Continuity Eq.
            [(3)]
      [(4)]
      ]
      [Horiz. Momentum Eq.
      [(5)]
      ]
      [Hydrostatic Balance Eq.
      [(6)]
      ]
    ]
  \end{forest}
\end{sideways}

\end{document}


